# Not able to read PPT file using apache.poi library

Tags: apache-poi, hslf

I want to read a ppt file i tried to read file using apache.poi library API.
This is what i tried .

```
POIFSFileSystem posF = new POIFSFileSystem(fileInputStream);
```

it throws the following error

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 4851293027410584380, expected -2226271756974174256
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlockReader.<init>(HeaderBlockReader.java:112)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:151)
```

This question has been asked on stackoverflow many times and i tried all the suggested  solutions but it was of no use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i tried following code to check with Apache Tika.

POIFSContainerDetector detector = new POIFSContainerDetector();
 MediaType mdType= detector.detect(fis, new Metadata());

but it throws 

java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
 at java.io.InputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.POIFSContainerDetector.detect(POIFSContainerDetector.java:158)





any further help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That error tells you that your file isn't actually a PPT file after all. (It's not an OLE2 file, which is the underlying format that .PPT is based on)

To work out what your file actually is, I'd suggest using either the `file` utility on a nearby unix box, or use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) with the TikaCLI and --detect. That should help you work out what your file is (hint - it's not a .ppt hence the error!) then you can identify what library to use to open it with